# Restore rules from output of `iptables -S`

Tags: iptables

I have a bunch of rules dumped with `iptables -S`:

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT

etc...
```

Next time, I will do this via `iptables-save`, and `iptables-restore`.  But for now, is there a better way to restore my rules, other than:

```
iptables -F
xargs -n1 -d\\n iptables < iptables.dump
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly... probably not.  However... one point-of-interest... your `iptables -F` is insufficient for flushing ALL your tables.  (Yes, this is sufficient for flushing all the chains in the default `filter` table)  You must specify each table to flush, not just the default one.  i.e. `iptables -t nat -F` and/or `iptables -t mangle -F`.